# Putting examples in a different sentence

Tags: grammaticality, questions

If I were to ask a question like this:

> What type of glue is it?

And I need to provide some examples:

> Liquid, stick, etc.

Do I have to keep them in one sentence or could I split them into two?

For example, one sentence:

> Is the glue liquid, stick, etc.?

And split into two:

> Liquid, stick, etc.

Comment: Both are fine - you can even ask the question and then provide a list after the main question. (1) Is the glue liquid (pot) or a solid (stick)? (2) What type of glue is it? E.g. liquid (pot), solid (stick). (3) What type of glue is it - liquid (pot) or solid (stick)?

Comment: I've seen "What kind of glue is it?—liquid, stick, etc."

Comment: What other types of glue are there, apart from stick and liquid? I suppose there is superglue, wood glue, leather glue, hot glue, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any rule against naming examples in a separate sentence.

If you're specifically looking to find out the consistency of the glue, you could also ask:

> What is the glue's consistency?

That's more specific than "what type of glue" and might not even require naming examples. If you're asking the question in an informal setting, you could also write:

> What is the glue's consistency (liquid, stick, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write a sentence which is a list of items, but two sentences like

> What kind of glue is it? is it x, y, or z?

Works well. This lets you separate a complex question from a long list, which seems like a good idea?

> who is your favourite literary character whose name alliterates? Is it Mickey Mouse, Peter Parker, Donald Duck ...